# Spring Candidate Bean Type Strategy should not instantiate all beans of given type before checking qualifier

Tags: java, spring

Having, an application with a multiple databases, and a Custom EntityManager scope.

I figured that Spring creates all beans condidates for some Type, before filtring the qualified one.

So in my case, its open all the EMFs even if i need to open only one !

The debuging bring me to thoses part of code which cause the problem :
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils

```
/**
  * Obtain a bean of type {@code T} from the given {@code BeanFactory} declaring a qualifier
  * (e.g. {@code <qualifier>} or {@code @Qualifier}) matching the given qualifier).
 */
private static <T> T qualifiedBeanOfType(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf, Class<T> beanType, String qualifier) {    
    Map<String, T> candidateBeans = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(bf, beanType);
 -> Spring is looking for all bean condidate with the given Type before testing the qualifier
        T matchingBean = null;
        for (String beanName : candidateBeans.keySet()) {
            if (isQualifierMatch(qualifier, beanName, bf)) {
            ........
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the creation part

```
    public <T> Map<String, T> getBeansOfType(Class<T> type, boolean includeNonSingletons, boolean allowEagerInit)
                throws BeansException {
    
        String[] beanNames = getBeanNamesForType(type, includeNonSingletons, allowEagerInit);
        Map<String, T> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, T>(beanNames.length);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            try {
               result.put(beanName, getBean(beanName, type));
-> the bean is created even if its not the qualified one
            }
    ...........
            }
        }
```

I can modify the Spring code to find the qualified Bean before creating all beans condidates, but i wonder if there is another way to do?

Comment: Did you file a ticket or something?

Comment: Couldn't find one so created https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The improvement has been accepted and was rolled out in versions 4.1.9 and 4.2.4.
See the bug-report for details: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13741

Answer (score -1):

There is a lazy bean instantiation in context.xml :

```
lazy-init="true"
```

http://www.javabeat.net/how-to-lazy-initialize-spring-beans/